# Редирект в wordpress через go

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Нужно сделать на вордпресс редирект в виде mysite.com/go/newsite.com. Может кто знает как или в какую сторону копать?

Comment: Нужно - реализовывайте.

Comment: Нужно написать скрипт, работающий на mysite.com/go и принимай параметры в виде целевых адресов. Обязательно проверять эти адреса на разрешенные иначе сайт быстро превратить в клоаку для слива трафа на всякое дерьмо. Но лучше этого вообще не делать.